# filtering duplicate string in database

Tags: sql-server

My application sends bulk messages to customers. What I want is:

1.Application should not accept more than 10 duplicate message per day.
2.should be checked for same sender, same number and on same message.

How can i do it in database?
The sent message details are saved in a table and it has columns to store sender id, mobile no, message and datetime

Before insertion, the condition should be checked.

please help me out.

Comment: If you are allowing your application to send the same message even twice, I would not want to be in your 'customer' list.

Comment: i was doing kinda same job using java for a different issue.  now this filtering should be done in database level so i don't have any idea.

Comment: If you'd limit it to 1 identical message per day, you could put a unique constraint on the date, sender, customer number and message table.

Comment: Please can you be more specific in your question? The solution depends on how and when you need to make the validation. For example: it's different if you need to check before inserting than a validation once all the data is loaded.

Comment: i want to check it before the insertion in the database.

Comment: Add a new column in table which update for every user for his msg.. by this way you can check .. if he has sent 10 msgs then you can avoid ..

Answer (score 0):

You can create trigger on table to validate it, or check on the UI by the query before inserting.